# Variable for User Field

Tags: variable, user-profile, usermodel, current-user

How do I go about using a dynamic value to access a user field value? I have created a form builder for users and dynamically populate the user field based on the question's associated field.

```
<input name="fields[{{ question.fieldName }}]">
```

This works nicely but I am looking to pre-populate this input with a value if the user has previously provided and saved this info but I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine the field name with currentUser.

My first try was:

```
{% set fieldName = question.fieldName %}
{{ currentUser.fieldName }}
```

But that returns the following error:

Craft\UserModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "fieldName".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [`attribute`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function in twig, this should let you call dynamic properties.

Something like:

```
{{ attribute(currentUser, question.fieldName) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tested it but get returned the following error: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Comment: What values are you getting if you dump `question.fieldName`?

Comment: Sorry, using the attribute function did work. I just needed to to adjust it to use question.fieldName.value so I set that as a variable as such:
    
    {% set questionField = category.fieldName.value %}
    {{ attribute(currentUser, questionField ) }}

Thanks!